# Configuring new developer PC with VISTA 64-bit: can I use my 32-bit Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-vista, 64-bit

I'm about to take the plunge and build a PC, and it will probably be 64-bit, which will use 64-bit VISTA, I suppose, since Windows 7 isn't out yet.

I'm a Visual Studio 2008 developer; will I need new versions of the software? I run the 32-bit versions on XP right now and deploy to a 64-bit Windows 2003 server that runs IIS in 32-bit mode.

Comment: If you download the Windows 7 release candidate, it should run until you can buy a released version.

Comment: @Mark Ransom - I would also advocate Win7 over Vista but it is worth noting that currently there is not an official upgrade path from Windows 7 RC to RTM and the final release date may not be for some time after the RC expires.

Comment: I'm running Win7 and it's so good that I'd recommend using the RC and just dealing with the fact that you'll have to reinstall once the real thing comes out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 only has a 32-bit version. This runs fine on Vista x64 and Win7 x64 though.

Comment: Great blog post about the topic
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx